# Pagination - Every page still first page Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination

I got a problem on my CI.
I’m using CI pagination, however when I got to page 2/3… the first page still marqued.
**Everytime I change of page the content change too, but the first page still marked 1**
The function URL is :

**uri->segment(4)
www.site.com/controller/function/index/1(page number)**

**Function :**

```
$this->load->helper("url");
        $limite = 6;
        if ($this->uri->segment(4) == ""):
            $data['start'] = 0;
        else:
            $data['start'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
            $data['start'] = ($data['start']-1)*$limite;
        endif;

        //Carregar a livraria paginação
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        //URL Base
        $config['base_url']     =   base_url().'item_shop/armaduras/index/';
        //Total de registos
        $config['total_rows']   =   $this->item_shop_model->contar_armaduras($limite,$data['start']);
        //Numero de links
        $config['num_links']    =   5;
        // Segmento que conterá o parâmetro de incremento
        $config['uri_sigments'] =   3;
        $config['per_page']     =   $limite;
        $config['first_page']   =   1;

        // Configuracoes de estilo da url
        $config['first_link'] = '<<';
        $config['last_link'] = '>>';
        $config['next_link'] = '>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;     

        // Iniciamos as configuracoes e criamos o link para o acesso
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination']     =   $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['items']          =   $this->item_shop_model->select_all_armaduras($limite,$data['start']);
        $data['title']          =   "HeroM2 Servidor Privado de Metin2";
        $this->load->view('shop-2',$data);
```

When I use the index function controller, it’s work perfectly :

**uri->segment(3)
www.site.com/controller/index/1**

**Index Function :**

```
$this->load->helper("url");
        //Limite de registos
        $limite = 6;
        if ($this->uri->segment(3) == ""):
            $data['start'] = 0;
        else:
            $data['start'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $data['start'] = ($data['start']-1)*$limite;
        endif;

        //Carregar a livraria paginação
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        //URL Base
        $config['base_url']     =   base_url().'item_shop/index/';
        //Total de registos
        $config['total_rows']   =   $this->item_shop_model->contar_espadas($limite,$data['start']);
        //Numero de links
        $config['num_links']    =   5;
        // Segmento que conterá o parâmetro de incremento
        $config['uri_sigments'] =   3;
        $config['per_page']     =   $limite;
        $config['first_page']   =   1;

        // Configuracoes de estilo da url
        $config['first_link'] = '<<';
        $config['last_link'] = '>>';
        $config['next_link'] = '>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;     

        // Iniciamos as configuracoes e criamos o link para o acesso
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination']     =   $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['items'] = $this->item_shop_model->select_all_espadas($limite,$data['start']);
        $data['title'] = "HeroM2 Servidor Privado de Metin2";
        $this->load->view('shop-1',$data);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: what's your pagination `uri_segment` configuration?

Comment: $this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url']  =  base_url().'item_shop/armaduras/index/';
$config['total_rows']  =  $this->item_shop_model->contar_armaduras($limite,$data['start']);
$config['num_links'] = 5;
$config['uri_sigments'] =  3;
$config['per_page']  =  $limite;
$config['first_page']  =  1;
$config['first_link'] = '<<';
$config['last_link'] = '>>';
$config['next_link'] = '>';
$config['prev_link'] = '<';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

Comment: Could you please update that info, and all other interesting info directly to the question. They may get better styling and are readable in one place, not spread in individual comments. Just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

when url is `www.site.com/controller/function/index/1` the `uri_segment` configuration should be 4

Comment: That's what I'm using.
In the index function, I use uri_segment 3 and in the another functions I use uri_segment 4.

I can change page content, but the first page still marqued.

Comment: maybe you don't need a `index` in your uri_segment, while the function is not `index`, and set the uri_segment to be 3 as same as the index function

Comment: The limit will be -6 / 6 :|